# data.table and character vectors

Tags: r, data.table

In my work, I often refer to lists of variables as just one character vector.

```
A <- data.table(var1 = 1:10, var2 = 11:20, var3 = 21:30)
vecvar <- c("var1", "var2", "var3")
```

Whenever possible, I want to use `vecvar` rather than enumerate the variables, as this makes my code more robust to future applications to slightly different lists of variables.

I recently discovered `data.table`, and as much as I love the general elegance of the syntax and the efficiency gains, I find that it clashes a bit with my inclination outlined above. Indeed, `A[, vecvar]` won't work.

I am undecided as to the best way to work around this.

`A[, vecvar, with=F]` will work, but is not always convenient (e.g. `A[, list(vecvar, var1+var2), with=F]` won't work).

`A[, sapply(vecvar, get)]` won't work, though `A[, sapply(vecvar, function(x) get(x))]` will.

I am not stuck, as I have ways to deal with it -- I just want to know what the best way to work with this is, before I pick up bad habits!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I kind of see what you mean. Does [FAQ](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf)1.6 help?  Also, there were a few threads on datatable-help about using quote()-ed expressions in data.table.

Comment: Hi -- Thanks for the reply, and sorry for the delay in this comment! Yes, quote()-ed expressions have the potential to help; but there is a missing bridge that I was not able to build between a character vector, and a quote()-ed expression usable in data.table. I am guessing that this is feasible; if so, it would indeed solve my problems!

Comment: Having exactly the same problem as @crayola. Unfortunaltely I can't see the brigde between a charater vector and a quote. The parse(text=) dind't help me out. Could anyone help with a minimal example?

Answer (score 1):

is this what you want to do?

```
> subset(A, select=vecvar[1:2])
      var1 var2
 [1,]    1   11
 [2,]    2   12
 [3,]    3   13
 [4,]    4   14
 [5,]    5   15
 [6,]    6   16
 [7,]    7   17
 [8,]    8   18
 [9,]    9   19
[10,]   10   20
```

Comment: Hi -- not really, as this uses the data.frame structure but can't be combined seamlessly with the data.table capabilities.
For example I'd like a very short statement that returns within a data.table: vecvar, var1+var2 (within explicitly mentioning var1 and var2 in vecvar) All the ways I have thought of so far make this a little more convoluted than should be necessary.